# difference between sonar and sonarqube

Tags: eclipse, integration, sonarqube

Can anybody explain me what is the difference between sonar and sonarQube as i have said to integrate the sonar with eclipse i am using eclipse Luna but when i tried to search sonar using

```
Help----> Eclipse Marketplace ---->search (sonar)
```

i am getting sonarQube not sonar
Therefore my question is  that are they same or different if same i can go ahead to install in the eclipse if not then from where to install sonar as it is my requirement.please anybody suggest

Answer (score 12):

`SonarQube (formerly just "Sonar")` is a server-based system. Of course you can install it on your local machine (the hardware requirements are minimal). But it is a `central server with a database`.

Analyses are performed by some `Sonar` "client" software, which could be the sonar runner, the sonar ant task, the sonar Eclipse plugin etc. The analysis results can be automatically uploaded to the server, where they can be accessed via the sonar Web application.

In an environment with many developers, you should run a build server (e.g. Hudson or Jenkins), which performs automatic sonar analyses as part of the nightly build. Other schedules are possible, but the developers should know when they can expect updates of the server-side analysis results. The results of the automated analysis can be displayed in the individual developer's `Eclipse` editor by way of the sonar Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Same software. The name changed last year, from Sonar to SonarQube
http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-becomes-the-sonarqube-platform/

Comment: Add: Make sure it's "SonarQube" not "Codesonar", which is another tool.

Answer (score 4):

From [SonarQube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube)

> SonarQube (formerly Sonar) is an open source platform for continuous inspection of code quality.

From http://www.sonarqube.org/

> SonarQube™ software (previously known as “Sonar”) is an open source project hosted at Codehaus.